# Validation messages are displaying at the bottom of the page JSF - javax faces developmentstage messages

Tags: jsf

I am stuck with displaying error message in JSF.  My requirement is given below:

I have a user form, where the user has to enter details like firstname, lastname, username and emailaddress.  All these fields are mandatory, among these fields, username and emailaddress are unique.  So when the user enters all the fields, and if he clicks save then at the backend I have to check whether username and email address already exists in the db, if it exists i have to show error message on the top of the page saying "the data entered is already exists, please reenter again".

And validation messages for firstname and lastname should display on the side of each field.  I can't use `<h:messages>` because it displays all the validation messages at once.

so I am populating a hidden field in the form with the message using the following code:

```
context.addMessage("addUserErrorMessage", new FacesMessage("the data entered is already exists, please reenter again"));
```

`addUserErrorMessage` is id of the hidden form field.

But when I am displaying message at the top of the page as

```
<h:message for="addUserFormMessage">
```

the message is being displayed at the bottom of the page
when I inspect through firebug, I found the following tags are populating

```
<ul id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages" title="Project Stage[Development: Unhandled Messages">
    <li style="color:red;">the data entered is already exists, plese reenter again </li>
</ul>
```

I am not able to find out, why the message is showing at the bottom, as I written `<h:message>` tag of the top of the page.

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible somehow that your previous experimentation with `<h:messages>` hasn't completely been removed from the JSF file?

Answer (score 2):

> *so I am populating a hidden field in the form with the message using the following code:*
>
> ```
> context.addMessage("addUserErrorMessage", new FacesMessage("the data entered is already exists, please reenter again"));
> ```
>
> *addUserErrorMessage is id of the hidden form field.*

The `addMessage()` expects a client ID as first argument, not a component ID. The client ID should look like `formId:addUserErrorMessage`. The client ID is basically the HTML DOM element ID. Open the page in browser, rightclick it, *View Source*, locate the hidden input and figure its `id` attribute.

---

As a completely different (and more commonly used) alternative, just don't abuse a hidden input, but just set `null` as client ID:

```
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
```

This way the message will be set as *Global* message and you can use the `globalOnly` attribute of the `<h:messages>` to display *Global* messages only.

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```